# Ardvark simulation game in CoolBASIC programming has error only when running

Tags: runtime-error, basic

I have this problem that in my code all working fine, just when I run that it gets to crash just before finish.

```
'*** Game Setup Function
Function setup_game()
    SCREEN 1024, 768, 32
    ShowMouse OFF
    FrameLimit 32
EndFunction

'*** Player Creation function ***
Function Setup_player()
    player_still = LoadAnimObject("Media\Sprites\Ardvark_still.png", 100,100, 1,7)
EndFunction 

'*** Setup the game
setup_game()
setup_player()


'*** Game Loop ***
Repeat
    PlayObject my_ardvark, 1,8, 0.9
    DrawScreen
Forever
```

The error I get says `Memory Access Violation` error.

I do know which error `Memory Access Violation` is, just not where it means because it no has `player_still`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `player_still` variable inside `Setup_player()` is **local** to the function.

That means that the game crashes when you try to access the non-existing object `player_still`.
Define global variable named "player_still" in the main code, or just put `Global` in before you assign it from the function, like this:

```
Function Setup_player()
    Global player_still = LoadAnimObject("Media\Sprites\Ardvark_still.png", 100,100, 1,7)
EndFunction
```